# batch file to search sub directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-shell

I have a script i am trying to alter to search multiple sub directories within a given path, then copy the files found to location create folder with the copied files in folder file was ran from. At the moment script works but does to search sub directories, How do i alter my script below please.

```
@echo off
set LIST= C:\batch\list.txt
set FILESPATH="C:\Test"
for %%i in ("%LIST%") do set DEST=%%~ni
for /F "usebackq delims==" %%i in (%LIST%) do (call :COPY_FILES "%%i")
:COPY_FILES
xcopy /qv %FILESPATH%\%1 .\%DEST%\*
```

I have tried to alter this line

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b "%LIST%"') do (call :COPY_FILES "%%i"), but gets an error that the file list.txt could not be found.

Thanks

Comment: You are getting the last line of `c:\batch\list.txt` for the destination folder.  Is that what you want to do?  Add `/s` to the xcopy command to include subdirectories.

Comment: inside list.txt is a list of file names that the script use to search the specified folder C:\Test. this works fine, however i need the script to search all sub directories inside the path C:\Test.

Comment: I disagree that it works fine, in that case.  `%dest%` is being set to part of, or the whole of, the last line in `%list%`

Answer (score 0):

Test this: it will only print the xcopy lines to the console.

If it seems right then remove the `echo` from the xcopy line and run it for real.

If the commands are not right then provide a sample of the lines to see which part is wrong.

```
@echo off
set "LIST=C:\batch\list.txt"
set "FILESPATH=C:\Test"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%LIST%") do (
    echo xcopy /s/h/k/f/c/q/v "%FILESPATH%\%%i" "%%~ni\"
)
pause
```

Comment: ok i have tried your version, however its now not able to find the files which are listed in list.txt.

Comment: c:\batch>list.bat
0 File(s)
0 File(s)
0 File(s)
File not found - 247.LOG
0 File(s)
File not found - 247.TXT
0 File(s)
Press any key to continue .

This is the error

Comment: Try the above code - it will echo the command lines.  Show me one of those please.

Comment: xcopy /s/h/k/f/c/q/v "C:\Test\247.TXT" "247\"
above is one of the lines that appears

Comment: If there is a file called `247.txt` in any folder under `c:\test` then it should be copied to a folder called `247` in the current directory (including folder structure), when you remove the `echo` keyword.

Comment: still getting same error, would also like to call the copied file List as in the previous script.